# How to serialize a 2d array to a text file in C#?

Tags: c#

I am working with 2D arrays (around 500 of them).
I need to print them in a text file in a particular format.

For now I just loop through each element of each 2D array and writing in the text file.

Is there a better way to do this?

This is the format I want my 2D arrays to be printed as :

```
8 5 1 |6 6 2 |4 5 1 
7 2 3 |5 3 6 |6 2 9 
5 6 4 |3 6 4 |6 7 4 
------+------+------
1 2 4 |1 8 7 |4 8 2 
3 8 5 |3 2 8 |9 1 7 
8 4 6 |3 2 8 |4 5 5 
------+------+------
3 5 7 |4 8 8 |5 7 5 
2 1 7 |8 7 8 |4 5 3 
3 4 5 |7 3 6 |9 4 3
```

Comment: nope theres not likely a better way.

Comment: What do you mean better way? What do you want to achieve which is not achieved with your current solution?

Comment: Must the file be human readable or can it be binary (save memory)? Is there a limit to the size of the array and/or the values?

Comment: @pid has to be human readable

Comment: @JacquesB I mean more optimized way, If I write each character one at a time, it is taking lot of time. Like while reading I am able to Read all text at once and then parse them, I was thinking of a better way to write at once.

Comment: @Charu: You should edit the original question to include that. As it stands, the question is going to be closed, since it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

1. you are writing sudoku so the array has the given grid of values in the range 1 to 9
2. you have profiled your application and found that writing them using conventional string and writer operations is a performance issue

Then you can set up an array of around 250 bytes containing the ASCII equivalent of your table, populated by zeros. This is your buffer. Then for each value in your 2D array of numbers, update the corresponding byte in the buffer. Then write the buffer in one go to a raw stream rather than using a stream writer. This will save any encoding overhead, and the overhead of any temporary string creation, any processing to handle multi-digit integers, and anything associated with making multiple calls on the stream writer.